Property of convex minorant and affine lower bound on a subset
Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $\underline{f}\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ denote its convex minorant, i.e.,
$$
\underline{f}(x) = \sup \big\{g(x) :\, g \leq f, g~\text{convex}\,\big\}.
$$
I am reading a paper, where they claim the following is true:

Let $A \subset\mathbb{R}$ be any set, and $h \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ an affine function. If $h|_A \leq f|_A$ then $h|_A \leq \underline{f}|_A$.

I am having difficulty establishing this, which would seem to require finding convex $\phi$ that is a global lower bound, i.e., $\phi \leq f$, with $\phi|_A \geq h|_A$.
EDIT: This seems to be false? Can't we take $A = \{x\}$ and $h(y) \equiv f(x)$. Then trivially, it holds that $h|_A \leq f|_A$ however if the claim holds then it would seem to imply that $f(x) \leq \underline{f}(x) \leq f(x)$, which implies that $f = \underline{f}$ everywhere?

This is false, but I don't think your counterexample is valid. You could have, for example, $f(x) = (x-2)^2(x+2)^2$, let $A = [-1, 1]$, and $h(x) \equiv 9$. Then $h(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in A$, but $\underline{f}(x) \equiv 0$ on $A$.

I'm not quite following it, but it seems like you are trying to conclude that, from $f(x) = \underline{f}(x)$ for a specific $x$, that $f = \underline{f}$ everywhere? Why would that hold? It's perfectly possible for $f$ and $\underline{f}$ to agree at a single point (or more) without being identical.

"Well, if the claim holds, we can apply it to any A right?" OK, I see where you're coming from. No, the result does not assume that $h$ and $f$ are functions such that $h|_A \le f|_A$ for all $A$. It fixes a subset $A$, a function $f$, and affine function $h$, and draws conclusion from there. Changing the subset $A$ may cause the premises to no longer hold true.

I have added a clear answer to this question.

The claim is false, and in fact is false for every $f$ which is not convex.

Equivalent reformulation of claim:
Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the set of triples $(h, h', B)$ where $h, h' \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, where $h$ is affine, $h'$ is continuous, and $h(x) \leq h'(x) $ for all $x \in B$.
The claim can be rewritten as the implication
$$
(h, h', B) \in \mathcal{I} \implies (h, \underline{h'}, B) \in \mathcal{I}.
$$

Deriving a contradiction:
Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function which is not convex. With the choices
$$
h_x(y) = f(x) \quad \mbox{and} \quad A_x = \{x\},
$$
we have $(h_x, f, A_x) \in \mathcal{I}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The claim implies that
$$
(h_x, \underline{f}, A_x) \in \mathcal{I} \quad \mbox{for all}~x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Equivalently, $\underline{f}(x) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\underline{f} \leq f$, this is equivalent to
$$
\underline{f}(x) = f(x) \quad \mbox{for all}~x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
This, equivalently, means $f$ is convex, a contradiction.
